# Can dup2 really return EINTR?

Tags: linux, posix, freebsd, language-lawyer, file-descriptor

In the spec and two implementations:

- According to POSIX, `dup2()` may return EINTR.
- The linux man pages list it as permitted.
- The FreeBSD man pages indicate it's not ever returned. Is this a bug - since its close implementation can EINTR (at least for TCP linger if nothing else).

In reality, can Linux return EINTR for `dup2()`? Presumably if so, it would be because `close()` decided to wait and a signal arrived (TCP linger or dodgy file system drivers that try to sync when closing).

In reality, does FreeBSD guarantee not to return EINTR for `dup2()`? In that case, it must be that it doesn't bother waiting for any outstanding operations on the old fd and simply unlinks the fd.

What does [POSIX `dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) mean when it refers to "closing" (not in italics), rather than referencing the actual `close()` function - are we to understand it's just talking about "closing" it in an informal way (unlinking the file descriptor), or is it attempting to say that the effect should be as if the `close()` function were first called and then `dup2()` were called atomically.

> If *fildes2* is already a valid open file descriptor, it shall be closed first, unless *fildes* is equal to *fildes2* in which case *dup2()* shall return *fildes2* without closing it.

If `dup2()` *does* have to close, wait, then atomically dup, it's going to be a nightmare for implementors! It's much worse than the EINTR with `close()` fiasco. Cowardly POSIX doesn't even say if the dup took place in the case of EINTR...

Comment: In Linux `dup2` is atomic.

Comment: Thanks. The point is, that's potentially extremely hard to implement if `dup2()` does the same waiting that `close()` does. The `close()` implementation unlinks the entry in the fd table, then waits on the remaining file struct. If it's interrupted, the fd is closed. How could the dup2 implementation be atomic if it has to wait - obviously it can't keep a lock on the fd table in that time, so you'd get into a mess where both the EMFILE and EINTR errors occur...

Comment: The library documentation says the operation cannot be interrupted, and it doesn't list EINTR as a possible error. Presumably it's implemented differently from `close`.

Comment: You can retry the `dup2` call if you get an `EINTR`, though.  So in some ways it's less of a disaster...

Comment: @teppic: *atomic* is not an issue here. *atomic* means: either it succeeds, or it fails. And it can fail. And if it does fail, no harm has been done. (such as: closing a file, but not dupping the new fd over it)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the relevant information from the C/POSIX library documentation with respect to the standard Linux implementation:

```
 If OLD and NEW are different numbers, and OLD is a valid
 descriptor number, then `dup2' is equivalent to:

      close (NEW);
      fcntl (OLD, F_DUPFD, NEW)

 However, `dup2' does this atomically; there is no instant in the
 middle of calling `dup2' at which NEW is closed and not yet a
 duplicate of OLD.
```

It lists the possible error values returned by `dup` and `dup2` as `EBADF`, `EINVAL`, and `EMFILE`, and no others. The documentation states that all functions that can return EINTR are listed as such, which indicates that these don't. Note that these are implemented via `fcntl`, not a call to `close`.

Comment: My linux manpage *does* list EINTR as a possible error return.

Comment: @wildplasser - this is from the library documentation itself; the manpages are not always correct.

Comment: There's an error in docs here somewhere then. If `dup2()` really is equivalent to `close()` followed by `fcntl()`, then what happens if `close()` returns EINTR? I really suspect there's an error in these docs, but we'd have to check the kernel sources to find out. I'd be amazed to see the backflips it would take for `dup2` to both wait for TCP linger and be atomic.

Comment: @NicholasWilson - not necessarily. It says equivalent, but it doesn't say it's the same. It's possible there's an error, but I think it's unlikely, given how explicit the docs are on the return values.

Comment: OpenSuse 12.3 for dup2 lists 2 man pages (2) and (3p).  Both show EINTR as a possible error - cause: call was interrupted by a signal; see signal(7). 3p is POSIX  @teppic - so what did you cite in the answer above? --  please provide an URL.

Comment: @jimmcnamara - as I said above, the man pages are not necessarily correct (they are not provided by the library developers). I am quoting from the official library documentation - http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Duplicating-Descriptors.html#Duplicating-Descriptors

Comment: Per this: [http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html](http:////http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) POSIX does list EINTR as an errno returned by dup2. So, I do not know where teppic got his documentation, maybe he can share the source with us. Sorry for the digression, but getting this correct is pertinent to getting a good answer.

Comment: man pages are necessarily correct for the distro, however what you cited is NOT POSIX.  I don't care what GNU thinks POSIX is, opengroup.org is the final arbiter.  You may not agree.

Comment: @jimmcnamara - what POSIX says is completely irrelevant if the library doesn't implement it. As I pointed out, this is the standard implementation in Linux. Other Unix systems may be different.

Comment: @jimmcnamara - I didn't say that anywhere. glibc is the C/POSIX implementation in standard Linux systems, but it's certainly not 100% compliant with either. I'm also not saying that EINTR is definitely not returned, simply that according to the library documentation, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

8 years later this still seems to be undocumented.
I looked at the linux sources and my conclusion is that `dup2` can't return `EINTR` in a current version of Linux.

In particular, the function `do_dup2` in [fs/file.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.15/fs/file.c#L1032) ignores the return value of `filp_close`, which is what can cause `close` to return `EINTR` in some cases (see [fs/open.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.15/fs/open.c#L1325) and [fs/file.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.15/fs/file.c#L633)).

The way dup2 works is it first makes the atomic file descriptor update, and then waits for any flushing that needs to happen on close. Any errors happening on flush are simply ignored.